# Using es modules without transplier

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to use the module syntax without having to use an es6 to es5 transplier?

chrome dev 52 shows 100% support on https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

yet I still get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: Unfortunately 100% is not enough. While modules are part of the ES 2015 spec, loading them is a separate issue. As long as a browser has no module loader, import / export statements make no sense to it.

Comment: The `import` and `export` features are unfortunately some of the last es6 features to get support - I suspect Chrome isn't fully 100% yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 52 shows 98%, not 100%...

by the way, this is the chrome status: https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5365692190687232

Comment: 100% if you enable experimental features.